# one-sided t-test after a two-sided t-test?

Tags: t-test, mean, two-way

I have two groups and I conducted a two-sided $t$-test.

- mean group 1: 3.79
- mean group 2: 4.07
- $p$-value: 0.0081

The $p$-value is less than $\alpha$ = 0.05, hence, I can reject the null hypothesis of equal means and conclude that there is a difference between the mean of the two groups.

Is the mean of group 2 for sure bigger than the mean of group 1? Or do I have to conduct a one-sided $t$-test?

Comment: Is there a theoretical basis for your interest in one side?

Comment: (1) Nothing in statistics is "for sure."  (2) What would the result of the one-sided t-test be?  (You can compute it, by hand, in a fraction of a second from the information given.)

Comment: I want to compare the two groups and see if they differ in one variable. Right now I know that they are different, but does this result mean that the variable of interest is higher in group 2 compared to group 1.

Comment: The type of hypothesis you analyze is something you determine a priori.  Now that you've done the test, you can estimate the difference between the means and report a confidence interval for that difference.  Since you reject the null, the confidence interval for group2 mean - group 1 mean will only contain positive values, so you can be reasonably confident that the group  2 has a larger mean.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually simple:

Your two-sided t-test rejects the null hyothesis of equal population means at level $\alpha$. In addition to this, you see that sample mean 2 is larger than sample mean 1. Then the one sided conclusion "true mean 2 is larger than true mean 1" follows at level $\alpha$.

So your reasoning is basically correct and you even don't have to perform a one-sided test for this. Consulting the sample is sufficient for this step.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're modifying your statistical test *after* looking at the data; this is not good practice.

> Is the mean of group 2 for sure bigger than the mean of group 1? Or do I have to conduct a one-sided t-test?

The sample mean for group 1 is clearly smaller than the sample mean for group 2 (i.e., $\bar{x}_{1} < \bar{x}_{2}$). But you should **not** let your observation of the sample statistics drive your decision to use a one- or two-sided alternative. Based upon your question, it appears you are somewhat agnostic about directionality. I assume this, in part, by your decision to use a two-sided $t$-test. Even if the test was performed as a result of the default behavior of most software packages, a two-sided approach is preferred as you cannot articulate a strong theoretical basis for only being interested in one-side.

Again, you should not allow your observation of the test statistic to determine the direction of the test. Under a two-sided alternative, you split $\alpha$ evenly into the two tails. It is a more conservative test by design. The answer to your question is emphatically—no. You should not conduct a one-sided test after the discovery of a significant finding under a two-sided alternative. Your indifference to any one particular side, a priori, should be the deciding factor.

Comment: For a constructive counterpoint to your initial assertion about "not good practice," please see "A five-decision testing procedure" at https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00031305.2018.1437075.  It might cause you to rethink your emphatic "no."

Comment: @whuber I will give it a read. Do you recommend I revise that statement to one that is less categorical?

Comment: It's a good read.  I am interested in hearing your reaction once you have gone through it.